# Swift - unable custom cursor position from user in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, uitextfield

I have a textfield and I do not want users to be able to set the cursor position by touching and holding at the textfield. Is there a way to always have the cursor to be at the very end of the textfield?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? That sounds like a very bad user experience.

Comment: @rmaddy haha it actually does sound like it. So this is a textfield for typing in credit card number and I have created it so that every 4 numbers it adds a space in between. When a user sets a cursor position in the middle of the string and deletes or changes numbers, there's always a problem with adding spaces between the newly added numbers. It seems like stripe and paypal both have their UI's built so that users cannot set the cursor position in the middle of the textfield. If there's a better way to do this I'm willing to change it for the better user experience :)

Comment: Instead of making it difficult for the user to edit what they are typing, fix your code to add the spaces properly no matter where the user puts the cursor. I would suggest you redo your question to ask how to make your code work properly while formatting the text the user enters.

Comment: @rmaddy okay thanks for your feedback!

Comment: My suggestion for this , You should have two textfield 1) visible to screeen (User interaction would be false)2) invisible textfield which will get input from user (Make this textfield first responder programtically)

Comment: From that invisible textfield input fill that visible textfield (use TextfieldShouldChnageCharacterINrange delegate)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its not good to change this type of default behavior of textField.

As per your comment if you want to add credit card and you are facing some input complexity then I found code from my old project and might be it will work for you.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted) == nil

            if !replacementStringIsLegal {
                return false
            }

            let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            let components = newString.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted)

            let decimalString = components.joined(separator: "") as NSString
            let length = decimalString.length
            let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.character(at: 0) == (1 as unichar)

            if length == 0 || (length > 16 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 19
            {
                let newLength = (textField.text! as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

                return (newLength > 16) ? false : true
            }
            var index = 0 as Int
            let formattedString = NSMutableString()

            if hasLeadingOne
            {
                formattedString.append("1 ")
                index += 1
            }
            if length - index > 4
            {
                let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
                formattedString.appendFormat("%@ ", prefix)
                index += 4
            }

            if length - index > 4
            {
                let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
                formattedString.appendFormat("%@ ", prefix)
                index += 4
            }
            if length - index > 4
            {
                let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
                formattedString.appendFormat("%@ ", prefix)
                index += 4
            }


            let remainder = decimalString.substring(from: index)
            formattedString.append(remainder)
            textField.text = formattedString as String
            return false     
    }
```

Comment: That code is using a lot of non-Swift classes. Why use `NSString`, `NSCharacterSet` and `NSMutableString` in Swift?

Comment: @rmaddy - yes you are right I just found from my old project and didn't check. thats why I wrote might be work.

Comment: I urge you to update your answer to use proper Swift 4 syntax using Swift Strings and Swift classes.